# Mysql - Why can i not cast varchar to longtext?

Tags: mysql, casting, longtext

I can't seem to get my cast to work correctly

Below is my sample code

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  refname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  parent_id int UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  is_active int UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES test (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

  SELECT id, refname, parent_id, 1 AS depth, CAST(refname as LONGTEXT)
    FROM test
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Whenever i try to run this query it gives me

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LONGTEXT)     FROM test     WHERE parent_id IS NULL' at line 1

I have gone though several resources to try and identify what is wrong here, But I cannot seem to figure this out.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks all :)

Comment: Please review the manual for permissable cast types https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: @P.Salmon there is no mention in that link about longtext - I have already read though whats there :)